Dynamic dependencies in batched targets / generating target chains from an item group
I'm trying to use target batching to factor out common code between similar target chains, while allowing them to be scheduled independently and have diverging dependencies. I've reduced my main issue to the following demo:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Variants Include="VariantA;VariantB" TargetName="TargetFor%(Identity)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target
        Name="BatchedTarget"
        BeforeTargets="%(Variants.TargetName)"
    >
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Common code running for %(Variants.Identity)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="TargetForVariantA">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Inside TargetForVariantA" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="TargetForVariantB">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Inside TargetForVariantB" />
    </Target>
</Project>

When building the TargetForVariantA target, I would like BatchedTarget to execute only for the VariantA item. The BeforeTargets="%(Variants.TargetName)", which I wish would both batch BatchedTarget and setup the dependency properly, is not recognised and only produces a message visible in the .binlog file:
The target "%(Variants.TargetName)" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\dev\nrm-evol\nrm\tests.proj (9,3)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

What I've tried:

Using DependsOnTargets="BatchedTarget" on both TargetForVariant targets, of course, causes BatchedTarget to run for both variants.

Using BeforeTargets="@(Variants->'%(TargetName)')" on BatchedTarget manages to produce working dependencies, but understandably runs BatchedTarget for both variants as well.

Seeing that item transforms seems to work, I've tried the slightly cursed BeforeTargets="@(Variants->WithMetadataValue('Identity', '%(Variants.Identity)')->Metadata('TargetName'))", which turns out not to batch at all and expand to nothing (but no error message either this time).


Additional notes:

I would like these to remain data-driven, i.e. the Variants item group could be modified at evaluation time and include various metadata to drive the generated target chains.

I know running the MSBuild task on $(MSBuildProjectFullPath) with global properties to produce independent copies of the common target is a solution, but I'm afraid this will generate a huge amount of project instances (my real-world case is building 100~200 interdependent projects with a dozen different "variants"). The projects should also be able to override specific targets among the generated target chains, so I can't just isolate it in a separate .proj file and only MSBuild that.

The variants of BatchedTarget should be able to run at different points without waiting for one another in any way.


Is there any way to do this, or do I just have to accompany each addition to @(Variants) with a copy of BatchedTarget manually renamed for my new variant, and keep them all in sync?

The % character will only be understood as batching in specific contexts. In an answer that I wrote for "MSBuild - Introducing PackageReference based on specific condition", I have an explanation of the % character in MSBuild that might be helpful.

MSBuild can build multiple projects in parallel. Given a solution with multiple projects and/or a project with multiple project references, MSBuild will attempt to parallelize building the projects. MSBuild does not parallelize the targets within a given project. Do you have one set of source code (i.e. one project) that needs to be built in 100-200 variants? Or do you have 100-200 different sets of source code each with their own variances in the build steps? If the latter, make each set of source code a project and create a solution file that referencess all the projects.

On a target you can use batching in the Inputs and Outputs attributes. Other target attributes, including BeforeTargets, do not support batching. However, you can create an item collection that is a sub-set of the Variants item collection and provide that to BeforeTargets. Also, you can use Conditions with batching, e.g. <Message Importance="High" Text="Common code running for @(Variants)" Condition="'%(TargetName)'=='TargetForVariantA'"/>.

In a prior comment I implied a project per set of source code. A better way to put it is: there should be a project for each assembly.

@JonathanDodds I have a set of 100+ existing MSBuild projects, all importing a centralized custom targets file. I'd like to add logic to automatically gather a dozen different kinds of metadata about these projects, and a good portion of that logic is the same between kinds of metadata (scanning specifically-named directories next to each project file, gathering items created by each project as well as by its dependencies, etc). (cont)

I'm not looking for task parallelism, but to factor out this common logic while keeping the targets for producing and passing around different kinds of metadata independent. So no running targets for metadata that hasn't been requested, no syncing them all together. If BeforeTargets/AfterTargets/DependsOnTargets do not deal with batching at all, then I'm afraid what I want is simply not possible.

MSBuild always builds in terms of a specific project. Instead of trying to use a master item collection to determine which targets to run, could you use the project to set properties which in the common code enable/disable targets? If there are common patterns, you could have a property that sets other properties to enable a specific set of common targets. A given project only needs to know about itself. The big master item collection approach creates the item collection in every project although presumably a project uses only one item from the collection.

@JonathanDodds that's the thing, the master itemgroup should just indicate what targets to generate. Which ones to run and at which point should keep the vanilla behaviour. Basically these target chains are identical except for their names and the name of the items they generate, and although there is some support for dynamic item names (through CreateItem and such), there seems not to be the same flexibility for targets. As a point of reference, the approach I'm currently considering is to use a XML preprocessor to generate these similar target chains from a template.

It seems you are in an XY problem. Instead of asking how to do code reuse in MSBuild, you have already decided on an approach and are asking how to make that approach work.

Some general explanation about MSBuild is needed first.
MSBuild is not a procedural language; it's a declarative language.
MSBuild doesn't have subroutines. Targets are not subroutines.
MSBuild doesn't have branching. Because there is no branching, there are no flow control statements. That means there are no loop statements.
MSBuild has two datatypes: properties and items which are scalars and vectors, respectively.
There is no looping on items but there is 'batching' on items.
MSBuild has two phases when a project is 'run': Evaluation and Execution.
In the evaluation phase, properties and items that are not within a target are evaluated. The target build order is also determined in the evaluation phase.
In the execution phase, the targets are executed in the target build order. Properties and items within targets are evaluated when the target is executed.
Batching is not available in the evaluation phase. Batching only applies to the execution of targets and to the execution of tasks (which must be within targets).
Data driven targets from an Item
Given:
  <ItemGroup>
    <Variants Include="VariantA;VariantB" TargetName="TargetFor%(Identity)" />
  </ItemGroup>

it can be said that the Variants item has a VariantA item. But to be clearer, I will not overload 'item'. I will use 'Item Collection' and 'Item' and say that the Variants item collection has a VariantA item.
The target build order is created in the evaluation phase where batching can't be used. But that doesn't mean that an Item Collection can't be used to set a target order.
<!-- dynamic.proj -->
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SelectValue Condition="'$(SelectValue)' == ''">VariantA</SelectValue>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Set up Variants -->
        <Variants Include="VariantA" TargetOrder="Apple;Cat" />
        <Variants Include="VariantB" TargetOrder="Boat;Dog" />
        <Variants Include="VariantB" TargetOrder="Cat" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Get Items from Variants that match $(SelectValue) -->
        <Selected Include="@(Variants->WithMetadataValue('Identity', $(SelectValue)))" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Set MainDependsOn property from selected Variants items -->
        <MainDependsOn>@(Selected->'%(TargetOrder)')</MainDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="$(MainDependsOn)">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Main" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Apple" DependsOnTargets="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Apple" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Boat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Boat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Cat" DependsOnTargets="GetFoo" BeforeTargets="Dog">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Cat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Dog">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Dog" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target GetFoo" />
    </Target>
</Project>

Assume the above MSBuild code is saved in a file named dynamic.proj.
The command msbuild dynamic.proj (or msbuild dynamic.proj -p:SelectValue=VariantA) will produce the following output:
GetFoo:
  Inside Target GetFoo
Apple:
  Inside Target Apple
Cat:
  Inside Target Cat
Main:
  Inside Target Main

The command msbuild dynamic.proj -p:SelectValue=VariantB will produce the following output:
Boat:
  Inside Target Boat
GetFoo:
  Inside Target GetFoo
Cat:
  Inside Target Cat
Dog:
  Inside Target Dog
Main:
  Inside Target Main

Some things to note from the example:

The item function WithMetadataValue is used to perform the 'lookup' in the item collection.
Item collections allow duplicate values for Identity. WithMetadataValue returns both items for VariantB. For VariantB the MainDependsOn property has a value of Boat;Dog;Cat.
Apple and Cat both depend on GetFoo. The GetFoo target will be run once for the project.
DependsOnTargets will add targets to the target build order. BeforeTargets and AfterTargets only affect the order of targets. The Cat target has BeforeTargets="Dog". For VariantA, the Cat target is run and the Dog target is not run. For VariantB, the Cat and Dog targets are both run and the order is changed from Boat;Dog;Cat to Boat;Cat;Dog.

Code Re-use
Is a data driven approach (like the above) good for code re-use? Generally, no.
By design, projects are isolated and independent from each other. There is no shared global data. A very large item collection that is defined in a shared file will be created new in every project that uses the shared file. If there is only one item in the item collection that is of need for a specific project, then the time and space used by creating and accessing the item collection can be considered wasteful.
MSBuild is declarative and it is XML. The project itself is the data.
As an example, the following file named shared.Targets replaces the use of an item collection with just directly setting the MainDependsOn property based on the SelectValue property.
<!-- shared.Targets -->
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SelectValue Condition="'$(SelectValue)' == ''">VariantA</SelectValue>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Set MainDependsOn property from $(SelectValue) property -->
        <MainDependsOn Condition="'$(SelectValue)' == 'VariantA'">Apple;Cat</MainDependsOn>
        <MainDependsOn Condition="'$(SelectValue)' == 'VariantB'">Boat;Dog;Cat</MainDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Apple" DependsOnTargets="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Apple" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Boat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Boat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Cat" DependsOnTargets="GetFoo" BeforeTargets="Dog">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Cat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Dog">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Dog" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target GetFoo" />
    </Target>
</Project>

A project, in this example projA, declares the build variant it wants and imports shared.Targets.
<!-- projA.proj -->
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SelectValue>VariantA</SelectValue>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="$(MainDependsOn)">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Main" />
    </Target>

    <Import Project="shared.Targets" />
</Project>

The command msbuild projA.proj produces the output:
GetFoo:
  Inside Target GetFoo
Apple:
  Inside Target Apple
Cat:
  Inside Target Cat
Main:
  Inside Target Main

A more common approach is not to try to define the target build order. Instead define the target's dependencies on each other and optionally define properties to enable or disable certain steps.
The shared file might look like:
<!-- shared.targets -->
<Project>
    <Target Name="Apple" DependsOnTargets="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Apple" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Boat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Boat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Cat" DependsOnTargets="Apple;GetFoo" BeforeTargets="Dog">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Cat" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Dog" DependsOnTargets="Boat;Cat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Dog" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target GetFoo" />
    </Target>
</Project>

And the project file might look like:
<!-- projA.proj -->
<Project>
    <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="Cat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Main" />
    </Target>

    <Import Project="shared.targets" />
</Project>

Note that the files have become smaller and the output is the same.
Targets can be redefined
Let's say that projA.proj needs a different GetFoo.
<!-- projA.proj -->
<Project>
    <Target Name="Main" DependsOnTargets="Cat">
        <Message Text="Inside Target Main" />
    </Target>

    <Import Project="shared.targets" />

    <Target Name="GetFoo">
        <Message Text="Inside Target GetFoo as defined by projA" />
    </Target>
</Project>

After the Import, projA.proj redefines GetFoo.
The output of msbuild projA.proj will be:
GetFoo:
  Inside Target GetFoo as defined by projA
Apple:
  Inside Target Apple
Cat:
  Inside Target Cat
Main:
  Inside Target Main

If the alternative version of GetFoo is needed by more than one project, it can be placed in its own file that is imported.
SDK type projects are an example of code re-use
With .Net the standard build steps are all shared imported code and an SDK-style project may consist only of a PropertyGroup.

Alright, I did know most of this already but that's a good refresher and way more understandable than the documentation. So in the end, I got confused by the fact that target batching looks like it generates several independent instances of a target (especially in the MSBuild log viewer). But it actually is just an execution-time feature which runs the target for each item in a single batch, so there is no way to have it influence the dependency graph which is evaluation-time. (cont.)

In other words, target batching provides the target with a scope within which its properties and items may diverge from its other instances, but this is still a one-and-done thing and cannot propagate further to form distinct target chains, nor split the execution of a single batch to run the target instances at different points or under different conditions. Bottom line: as your "the project is the data" enlightens quite well, if I want several similar targets then I have to generate their declarations themselves, rather than relying on MSBuild functionality. Did I get all of this right?

Thank you for saying it was a good refresher. I would rather err by over-explaining than by not being helpful.

Batching only operates on item collections. Properties are unaffected. And the batch is only for the specified item collection. Yes, the target is executed multiple times but for each batch, not each item member. If you batch on a non-unique metadata value, the batches will have more than one item. (If you have only batched on Identity and Identity has always been unique, you may not have seen that subtlety.) Otherwise, yes, I think you got it right. :)

I mixed up the "separate scope for different target instances" with what CallTarget does. Target batching indeed does not isolate the target instances, that is each execution of the target can observe the side effects of the previous ones.
